# How to run bootnode in public IP in Ethereum Blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, etherscan

How can I run bootnode with my public IP address? I am running following command.

> bootnode --genkey=boot.key
> bootnode --nodekey=boot.key --writeaddress
> bootnode --nodekey=boot.key --addr:$(MY_PUBLICIP):30301
> Then I am getting following message

[image]

And if I replace MY_PUBLICIP with my actual Public IP it shows as follows.
[image]

What can I do, Please help me. Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
bootnode --genkey=boot.key && bootnode --nodekey=boot.key --addr :30301
```

Result:

```
enode://address@127.0.0.1:0?discport=30301
```

If

```
bootnode --genkey=boot.key && bootnode --nodekey=boot.key --addr 127.0.0.1:30301
```

Result:

```
enode://address@127.0.0.1:0?discport=30301
```

If

```
bootnode --genkey=boot.key && bootnode --nodekey=boot.key --addr IP_SERVER:30301
```

Result:

```
enode://address@IP_SERVER:0?discport=30301
```